# How can we check if Name field of Account object encrypted?

Tags: platform-encryption

There is 'isEncrypted()' method which when called on field of Contact object gives boolean result

`Boolean isFirstNameEncrypted = Contact.FirstName.getDescribe().isEncrypted();`

But Same do not happen if we use as

`Boolean isAccountNameEncrypted = Account.Name.getDescribe().isEncrypted();`

gives compilation issue

> Compilation problem  “Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or
>   incorrect signature: [Schema.DescribeFieldResult].isEncrypted() at
>   line 12 column 64”

As Org is enabled with "Person Account" and Platform Encryption feature, when We try to enable Encryption on Contact.Name , it implicitly try the same enablement for Account.Name field.

Is there any way to check if Name field of Account Encrypted or not?

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks
Manish

Comment: There's a difference between 'name' and 'first name'. You'd only be able to encrypt the first name of the person account which is something of a unique entity of and unto itself in the SF world. It creates challenges like this one since it doesn't fit all of the models and is somewhat "shoe-horned" into other objects.

Comment: were you able to find answer to this question?